# In sqlalchemy, how to define same table model(calss) quickly with only table name is different?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have 10 tables which are exactly same except the table name. And I don't want to combine 10 tables into one. Now I try to use sqlalchemy to insert data into these tables. I found I was repeating doing the following in my code :

```
class tableA(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(200))
    link = Column('link', String(200))

class tableB(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "B"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(200))
    link = Column('link', String(200))
    ......
    ......
class tableH(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "H"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(200))
    link = Column('link', String(200))
```

Can I use a single common table class with table name as a input to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do this, each with varying levels of verbosity and flexibility:

#### Common Base Class

```
class Foo(DeclarativeBase):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(200))
    link = Column('link', String(200))

class tableA(Foo):
    __tablename__ = "A"
```

#### Mixin

```
class Foo(object):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(200))
    link = Column('link', String(200))

class tableA(Foo, DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "A"
```

#### Dynamic `type`

```
def create_table(name):
    return type("table" + name, (DeclarativeBase,), {
        "__tablename__": name,
        "id": Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
        "title": Column('title', String(200)),
        "link": Column('link', String(200)),
    })

tableA = create_table("A")
```

Comment: Thank you! A lot to learn and I finally decide to use the Dynamic type, it works well!

Comment: @BushengLou In that case, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: one more question, before I use dynamic type, I can simply use create_all() create all the 10 tables in my database (if not exist). Now I need add a few more tables(say 20 tables now) , I found using dynamic type way, create_all() not works(obviously not work), I got error saying the new tables not exist in my database. Do you have any suggestions how to handle this issue?

Comment: @BushengLou `create_all()` still works if you dynamically create the classes. There's literally no difference between using `type()` vs using the `class Foo` syntax to create a class.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now all work perfectly. thanks a lot.